# How do i get the name of the button clicked, if they were created by a for loop?

Tags: python, button, get, click

the for loop looks like this (the list `words = ["box1", "box2", ..., "box100"]`):

```
for i in words:
        a = a + 1  
        i = tk.Button(window2, text = a, command = btn_press)
        i.config(height = '3', width = '5')
        i.place(x = -50 + a * 70, y = 25)
```

Also i have a randomly generated number and stored it as "boxX".
The problem is that when i try to:

```
def btn_press():
        guess = i['text']
        if guess == target:
            system('say you win!')
```

the variable guess is always box 100 (maybe since it was the last one to be created by the for loop?). please tell me i don't have to do 100 boxes by hand.

Comment: Instead of `command=` use `<button-reference>.bind('<Button-1>', btn_press)` and `def btn_press(event): event.widget['text']`

Comment: It tells me that <button-reference> has invalid syntax "<>", and when i delete them it says positional argument follows keyword argument highlighting the space before button-reference

Comment: *"invalid syntax "<>""*: It's a placeholder, replace it with your `= Button(...` reference, e.g. `btn = Button(...; btn.bind(...`.

Comment: @stovfl thanks a lot! and sorry for dumb questions